# "Run on live analysis" checkbox is not found in Visual Studio project properties/Code analysis tab

Tags: visual-studio-2019, code-analysis, project-properties

In Visual Studio 2019 v16.11.1, I could not find the "Run on live analysis" checkbox under project properties/Code analysis tab as shown in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2019). I did not find any information in msdn documentation as well. Please help me with what I miss here.
Screenshot is attached below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Run on Live Analysis" option is provided only for .Net Core or .Net Standard projects. As mine is a .Net Framework project Visual studio didn't show it.

As code analysis is a common feature for all type of projects, the UI should have been common. Not sure why Microsoft has this difference.